# How can separate the index from two app bar?

Tags: flutter, navigation, appbar

I have two appear one at the top and one at the bottom.However, if I tap on the top appbar the bottom navigation bar with change accordingly.I don't want this to happen , how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Create two intigers and then define them as index

```
int index1=0;//set whatever value you want as default
int index2=1;//set whatever value you want as default

BottomNavigationBar1(
 ...
index:index1
onTap:(index1){
   // what you want to do on index1 change
 }
)

BottomNavigationBar2(
 ...
index:index2
onTap:(index2){
  // what you want to do on index1 change
 }
)
```